# Android Studio Not Showing Error

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio v1.0 does not give update if there is error on my code or is a particular syntax is wrong.[image] is an illustration of the issue. 
 `int j = ""` suppose to be an error and the line ought to be mark red. But if does not. Only get notified that there is error on code when compiling the code.

Comment: It is giving the errors for both the cases

Comment: like implement hhjdf is suppose to give me a feedback that there is an error by marking the entire line. But i am getting non of these

Comment: Try to upgrade your Android Studio to the latest version.

Comment: [I found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801755/android-studio-not-detecting-errors) I hope it can help you